# Prepopulating and saving inlines in django-extra-views

Tags: django, django-forms, formset, inline-formset

I'm using django-extra-views and I wanted to fill a form and its associated inlines with prepopulated data and then save (create object). So far I have:

```
from extra_views import CreateWithInlinesView

class ItemCreateView(extra_views.CreateWithInlinesView):

    def dispatch(self, request, item_pk, *args, **kwargs):
        self.item = models.Item.objects.get(id=item_pk)
        return super(ItemCreateView, self).dispatch(
            request, *args, **kwargs
        )

    def get_initial(self):
        # Thanks to that method a form is populated with initial data.
        return forms.ItemCreateForm(instance=self.item).initial

    def construct_inlines(self):
        # Thanks to that method a form and its inlines are prepopulated successfully.
        ItemFormSet = inlineformset_factory(models.Item, models.ItemEntry, extra=0)
        formset = ItemFormSet(instance=self.item)
        return [formset]
```

However the object is saved without inlines, despite the fact that inlines values are sent via POST. What am I doing wrong? Should I initialize the form and inlines different way?